# How to sort table by column in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I use R package `nycflights13` and made a table in this way.

```
rk <- rank(-tab.0); rk 
carrier.top10 <- names(tab.0)[rk<=10]
flights.1 <- subset(flights, carrier %in% carrier.top10)
flights.1$badflight <- as.factor(flights.1$dep_delay >= 60)
levels(flights.1$badflight) <- c("good", "bad")
tab.2 <- with(flights.1, table(carrier, badflight))
tab.2m <- addmargins(tab.2)
2*prop.table(tab.2m, 1)

    badflight
carrier       good        bad        Sum
    9E  0.88567983 0.11432017 1.00000000
    AA  0.93662169 0.06337831 1.00000000
    B6  0.91406524 0.08593476 1.00000000
    DL  0.94348946 0.05651054 1.00000000
    EV  0.86400810 0.13599190 1.00000000
    MQ  0.91904781 0.08095219 1.00000000
    UA  0.93275151 0.06724849 1.00000000
    US  0.96080109 0.03919891 1.00000000
    VX  0.92886377 0.07113623 1.00000000
    WN  0.91028718 0.08971282 1.00000000
    Sum 0.91787917 0.08212083 1.00000000
```

Now, I wanna sort this file with decreasing order in `"good"` part.
What can I do?

Comment: Hello @hyeonny, in order to get more help, please provide a reproducible example as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `prop.table` you do not get a normal data.frame or matrix. You need to convert it into one and then use `order`. Try

```
data <- 2*prop.table(tab.2m, 1)
temp <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
temp[order(temp$good, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Tried it on this example using `mtcars`

```
data <- prop.table(with(mtcars, table(cyl, am)), 1)
temp <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
temp[order(temp$`0`, decreasing = TRUE), ]

#          0         1
#8 0.8571429 0.1428571
#6 0.5714286 0.4285714
#4 0.2727273 0.7272727
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by column is usually done by using order/sort:

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg), ]
```